# How do I set the alignment of a button right on a toolbar in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I try this below code but still the button was displayed on left side

```
<af:toolbar id="t3">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" layout="vertical" halign="right" inlineStyle="float:right;">
          <af:commandButton text="commandButton 1" id="cb1" inlineStyle="float:right;"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
</af:toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you resize the PanelGroupLayout inside the toolbar to be wider than the buttons? - then the button will be on the far right. My PanelGroupLayout inline width is: width:374px;  This gives me a PanelGroupLayout container that is wider than the buttons I have. Then I set the Halign to Right on the PanelGroupLayout and it worked fine. [image]

Source code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <af:document title="untitled2.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:form id="f1">
      <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
        <f:facet name="start"/>
        <f:facet name="end"/>
        <f:facet name="top"/>
        <f:facet name="bottom"/>
        <f:facet name="center">
          <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl2">
            <f:facet name="start"/>
            <f:facet name="end"/>
            <f:facet name="top"/>
            <f:facet name="bottom"/>
            <f:facet name="center">
              <af:toolbar id="t1">
                <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" inlineStyle="width:760px;" halign="right">
                  <af:button text="button 1" id="b1"/>
                  <af:button text="button 2" id="b2"/>
                </af:panelGroupLayout>
              </af:toolbar>
            </f:facet>
          </af:panelStretchLayout>
        </f:facet>
      </af:panelStretchLayout>
    </af:form>
  </af:document>
</f:view>
```